# Limit the size of Twitter oneboxes in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, twitter

Twitter links that contain multiple images can fill nearly a whole screen when they are one-boxed on chat. It's very annoying, and it would be much nicer if it was height-limited.

For example:

[image: Sample text]

There was a recent conversation about this:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40440917#40440917

Comment: Sometimes we see GIANT amazon ones too that don't even have images. I agree it should either be limited in size or the user should have the option to minimize/disable onboxes -or both-.

Comment: Room owners should also have the ability to disable oneboxing for a room. _Those kids and their cat pictures be damned_